# D3 flow graph was working, but doesn't display anything now

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some d3 code that uses force layout and I can't get it to display onscreen.  It was working earlier, so I know it is something small.

I have recently added code to pin the node when they are double clicked and the opposite when double clicked again.  They should also change colour.

```js
// get the data
links =  [
    {
      "source": "George Washington",
      "target": "John Adams",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Adams",
      "target": "George Washington",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Adams",
      "target": "Thomas Jefferson",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Thomas Jefferson",
      "target": "John Adams",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Thomas Jefferson",
      "target": "Aaron Burr",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Thomas Jefferson",
      "target": "George Clinton",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Thomas Jefferson",
      "target": "James Madison",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Madison",
      "target": "George Clinton",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Madison",
      "target": "Elbridge Gerry",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Madison",
      "target": "James Monroe",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Monroe",
      "target": "Daniel D. Tompkins",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Monroe",
      "target": "John Quincy Adams",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Quincy Adams",
      "target": "John C. Calhoun",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Quincy Adams",
      "target": "Andrew Jackson",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Andrew Jackson",
      "target": "John C. Calhoun",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Andrew Jackson",
      "target": "Martin Van Buren",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Martin Van Buren",
      "target": "Andrew Jackson",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Martin Van Buren",
      "target": "Richard M. Johnson",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Martin Van Buren",
      "target": "William Henry Harrison",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "William Henry Harrison",
      "target": "John Tyler",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Tyler",
      "target": "William Henry Harrison",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Tyler",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "John Tyler",
      "target": "James K. Polk",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "James K. Polk",
      "target": "George M. Dallas",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "James K. Polk",
      "target": "Zachary Taylor",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Zachary Taylor",
      "target": "Millard Fillmore",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Millard Fillmore",
      "target": "Zachary Taylor",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Millard Filmore",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Millard Filmore",
      "target": "Franklin Pierce",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Franklin Pierce",
      "target": "William R. King",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Franklin Pierce",
      "target": "James Buchanan",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Buchanan",
      "target": "John C. Breckinridge",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "James Buchanan",
      "target": "Abraham Lincoln",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Abraham Lincoln",
      "target": "Hannibal Hamlin",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Abraham Lincoln",
      "target": "Andrew Johnson",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Andrew Johnson",
      "target": "Abraham Lincoln",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Andrew Johnson",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Andrew Johnson",
      "target": "Ulysses S. Grant",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Ulysses S. Grant",
      "target": "Schuyler Colfax",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Ulysses S. Grant",
      "target": "Henry Wilson",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Ulysses S. Grant",
      "target": "Rutherford B. Hayes",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Rutherford B. Hayes",
      "target": "William A. Wheeler",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Rutherford B. Hayes",
      "target": "James A. Garfield",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "James A. Garfield",
      "target": "Chester A. Arthur",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Chester A. Arthur",
      "target": "James A. Garfield",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Chester A. Arthur",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Chester A. Arthur",
      "target": "Grover Cleveland",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Grover Cleveland",
      "target": "Thomas A. Hendricks",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Grover Cleveland",
      "target": "Benjamin Harrison",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Benjamin Harrison",
      "target": "Levi P. Morton",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Benjamin Harrison",
      "target": "Grover Cleveland",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Grover Cleveland",
      "target": "Adlai Stevenson",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Grover Cleveland",
      "target": "William McKinley",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "William McKinley",
      "target": "Garret Hobart",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "William McKinley",
      "target": "Theodore Roosevelt",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Theodore Roosevelt",
      "target": "William McKinley",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Theodore Roosevelt",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Theodore Roosevelt",
      "target": "Charles W. Fairbanks",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Theodore Roosevelt",
      "target": "William Howard Taft",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "William Howard Taft",
      "target": "James S. Sherman",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "William Howard Taft",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "William Howard Taft",
      "target": "Woodrow Wilson",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Woodrow Wilson",
      "target": "Thomas R. Marshall",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Woodrow Wilson",
      "target": "Warren G. Harding",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Warren G. Harding",
      "target": "Calvin Coolidge",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Calvin Coolidge",
      "target": "Warren G. Harding",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Calvin Coolidge",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Calvin Coolidge",
      "target": "Charles G. Dawes",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Calvin Coolidge",
      "target": "Herbert Hoover",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Herbert Hoover",
      "target": "Charles Curtis",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Herbert Hoover",
      "target": "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "target": "John N. Garner",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "target": "Henry A. Wallace",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "target": "Harry S. Truman",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Harry S. Truman",
      "target": "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Harry S. Truman",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Harry S. Truman",
      "target": "Alben W. Barkley",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Harry S. Truman",
      "target": "Dwight D Eisenhower",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Dwight D Eisenhower",
      "target": "Richard Nixon",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Dwight D Eisenhower",
      "target": "John F. Kennedy",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "John F. Kennedy",
      "target": "Lyndon B. Johnson",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Lyndon B. Johnson",
      "target": "John F. Kennedy",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Lyndon B. Johnson",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Lyndon B. Johnson",
      "target": "Hubert Humphrey",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Lyndon B. Johnson",
      "target": "Richard Nixon",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Richard Nixon",
      "target": "Spiro Agnew",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Richard Nixon",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Richard Nixon",
      "target": "Gerald Ford",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Gerald Ford",
      "target": "Richard Nixon",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Gerald Ford",
      "target": "Office Vacant",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Gerald Ford",
      "target": "Nelson Rockefeller",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Gerald Ford",
      "target": "Jimmy Carter",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Jimmy Carter",
      "target": "Walter Mondale",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Jimmy Carter",
      "target": "Ronald Reagan",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Ronald Reagan",
      "target": "George H.W. Bush",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "George H.W. Bush",
      "target": "Ronald Reagan",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "George H.W. Bush",
      "target": "Dan Quayle",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "George H.W. Bush",
      "target": "Bill Clinton",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Bill Clinton",
      "target": "Al Gore",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Bill Clinton",
      "target": "George W. Bush",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Geore W. Bush",
      "target": "Dick Cheney",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Geore W. Bush",
      "target": "Barack Obama",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Barack Obama",
      "target": "Joe Biden",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": "Barack Obama",
      "target": "Donald Trump",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "Donald Trump",
      "target": "Mike Pence",
      "value": "0"
    }
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 1200,
    height = 700,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-250)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

// Set the range
var  v = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 100]);

// Scale the range of the data
v.domain([0, d3.max(links, function(d) { return d.value; })]);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")

// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .style("stroke", function(d){
        if (d.value == 1){
            return d3.rgb(255, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            return d3.rgb(0, 0, 255);

        }
    });

// define the nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

svg.selectAll(".node").on('dblclick', function(d){
                       console.log("CLICKETY CLICK");
                       console.log(d);
                       if(!d.fixed) {
                           d.fixed = 1;
                           d3.select(this)
                             .select("circle")
                             .style("fill", "red");
                       }else {
                           d.fixed = 0;
                           d3.select(this)
                             .select("circle")
                             .style("fill", "LightGray");
                       }
                   });

var selection = d3.select("body").datum(43).append('h1');

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d,i){
        return (3 * d.weight) + 3;
    })
    .style("fill", "LightGray");

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 10)
    .attr("dy", function(d){
        return (5 * d.weight) + 3;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

// nodeUpdate.select("circle")
//           .style("fill", "red");

// add the curvy lines
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" +
            d.source.x + "," +
            d.source.y + "A" +
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
            d.target.x + "," +
            d.target.y;
    });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
};
```

```css
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  fill: #000;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="graph.css">
  <script src="graph.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody got any idea why nothing is getting displayed?

Comment: you include d3v5 and you use d3v3 syntax

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake.  That doesn't fix the problem.  I copied the line in because I was using a local version of d3.v3.  I just forgot to change the address when I copied and pasted.

Comment: it fixed it on my side, just 1 char change and I have a force graph. Have you clicked on "Run code snippet"?

Comment: It works here in the browser, but not on my system!!  I have added the https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js to mine, rather than use local, but still get a blank.  No errors in console.  I tried Chrome and Firefox and get the same...

Comment: Thank you.  Your comments got me to the solution...

Answer (score -1):

I needed to defer the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="graph.css">
  <script src="graph.js" defer></script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or add the script at the bottom of the `body` tag